# FOSUserBundle allow access to whole site

Tags: symfony, redirect, fosuserbundle

guys!
I'am trying to configure user system (FOSUserBundle) for my Symfony app. All was going Ok until I tried to allow access to whole site and restrict access to some routes using access control in security configuration file.

> ```
> firewalls:
>     main:
>         pattern: ^/
>         form_login:
>             provider: fos_userbundle
>             csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
>             default_target_path: /
>         logout:       true
>         anonymous:    true
>
> access_control:
>
>     - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
>     - { path: ^/profile$, roles: ROLE_USER }
>     - { path: ^/admin$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
> ```

I've tried also

> #
>   - { path: ^/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
>   #

and when i go to index page (/), it redirects me to login page. I want to have index page visible for all visitors, not only for those who logged in.

Just can't figure out this moment. Thank you for answers.

Comment: Try removing your first rule in access_control and change pattern in your main firewall to '/.*'

Comment: the same, it redirects me to login page

Comment: try with the * only without point or .+ - { path: ^/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

Comment: i've tried to set pattern to: ^/.* ^/* ^/.^/$ /$ /*+ and also path to same values, but it still redirects me to login page

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/profile$, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to trying to specify the role as an array of role but you give only one value:

```
- { path: ^/*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/profile$, role: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/admin$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

for more roles you need the []

Comment: yes, i've tried to use "role" instead of "roles", it gives no positive result

Comment: what about - { path: /*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } and comment other lines for test

Comment: the same, it redirects. i 've tried to change router path index (/) page to /index/, and it still redirects

Comment: when you login it goes to the index?

Comment: without any access_control it works right? i am afraid that access_control is not the problem

Comment: i've created page /admin for test, and set path ^/* to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY. admin page is opening for non logged in user, but /index/ page still redirecting me to login

Comment: i've tried to remove all paths from access control. /index/ page is redirecting, /admin/ page is opening

Comment: alright. so the problem is somewhere else, remove this default_target_path: / to try and how is your route configuration? is it possible that you index action is redirecting somehow? or requesting logged in user

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. Sorry for my dumbness, i've been wandering for 2 days why this happen.
Redirect was from controller. My mistake, sorry. Thank you for answers anyway.

```
public function startAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        return $this->render('HellfireCommonBundle:Index:index.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
    } else {    
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }
}
```